# Telnet by using Shellscript (OSX) with Expect

Tags: macos, shell, telnet

I want to connect a machine by telnet. Attempting to use Expect is not working. There is no username and password. Here is where I'm at.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

Echo Hello World
telnet IP_Address_Here 10001

expect "]'."
send "^a200\r"
```

This works up to the 'expect'. This is the result of the code...

```
Roberts-MacBook:~ rameeti$ sh test.sh
Hello World
Trying IP_Address_Here...
Connected to IP_Address.lightspeed.irvnca.sbcglobal.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

And then it sits waiting for the command that I want to send: "^a200"
Why is the 'expect' not working?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are executing it with `bash` instead of `expect`.

Otherwise, you will receive

```
invalid command name "Echo"
    while executing
"Echo Hello World"
```

try

```
$ expect -f test.sh
```

BTW, you should not name it `.sh` if it's expect.

Comment: I tried calling my script with your suggestion of 'expect...' after removing the Echo line. It then barked at my Telnet command so I added Spawn in front of the Telnet and it liked that better. But now, after connecting and giving me the connection response, it then immediately exits Telnet and takes me back to my command prompt. It is not liking the Expect or the Send apparently. Ideas?